# Issue with NSURLComponents when building a queryString

Tags: ios

I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab88c21750
```

And I get it with this code:

```
+ (NSString *)queryStringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)queryDictionary
{
    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@""];
    NSMutableArray *urlQueryComponents = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *key in [queryDictionary allKeys])
    {
        NSString *value = queryDictionary[key];
        NSURLQueryItem *newQueryItem = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key value:value];
        [urlQueryComponents addObject:newQueryItem];
    }

    components.queryItems = urlQueryComponents; // HERE I GET THE ERROR
    return [components query];
}
```

In the case where I got the error my queryDictionary looked like this:

```
{
    lat = "49.3437442";
    lng = "17.0571453";
    username = demo;
}
```

Another time when my queryDictionary looked like following, it worked fine!

```
{
    latlng = "49.343744,17.057145";
    sensor = true;
}
```

So I can't understand the issue or how I can fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: it's a type mismatch. you are passing a number object where a string is expected.

Comment: turn on exception breakpoints then look at the backtrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing a dictionary which contains an NSNumber as a key or value. `queryWithItem:value:` expects both key and value to be a string.

**OPTION 1**

the easiest way to fix this would be to treat all keys/values as NSObjects and use stringWithFormat to convert them into strings.

replace:

```c
NSURLQueryItem *newQueryItem = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key value:value];
```

with:

```
NSURLQueryItem *newQueryItem = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key] value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value]];
```

**OPTION 2**

if you want to insist that all keys are strings i'd recommend using generics for you input dictionary and to NSAssert if a non string key is found (so you can find your current error).

```
+ (NSString *)queryStringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary <NSString*, NSString*> *)queryDictionary {
    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@""];
    NSMutableArray *urlQueryComponents = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *key in [queryDictionary allKeys]) {
        NSString *value = queryDictionary[key];

        // confirm key/value are strings
        NSAssert([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]], @"keys must be strings!");
        NSAssert([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]], @"values must be strings!");

        NSURLQueryItem *newQueryItem = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key value:value];
        [urlQueryComponents addObject:newQueryItem];
    }

    components.queryItems = urlQueryComponents;
    return [components query];
}
```